# Resolvent: Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a Banach space.

Consider a closed operator:
$$T:\mathcal{D}(T)\to E:\quad T=\overline{T}$$

Due to the Neumann series it holds:
$$R(\lambda):=(\lambda- T)^{-1}:\quad\|R(\lambda)\|\geq\frac{1}{d(\lambda,\sigma(T))}\quad(\lambda\in\rho(T))$$
Can you give an example for strict inequality, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

Consider a nilpotent operator:
$$N\in\mathcal{B}(E):\quad N^K\neq0\quad N^{K+1}=0$$

Then its resolvent has a singularity at zero only:
$$\sigma(N)=(0):\quad(\lambda-N)^{-1}=\lambda\sum_{k=0}^K\lambda^{-k}N^k\quad(\lambda\neq0)$$

So the inequality necessarily becomes strict!

**Explanation**

Nilpotent operators have singularities of higher order at zero.

Normal operators have singularities of first order at zero.

Bounded quasinilpotent operators have essential singularities at zero ($\dim E=\infty$).

Note that a matrix whose resolvent has only poles of order one is diagonalizable.

Comment: Don't you have for $\lambda_0\in\rho(T)$ that $|\lambda-\lambda_0|<\frac{1}{R(\lambda_0)}$ implies $\lambda\in\rho(T)$? In turn, shouldn't this give $d(\lambda_0,\sigma(T))\geq\frac{1}{R(\lambda_0)}$?

Comment: If your inequality held for nilpotent matrix $N$ of order 2, then it would imply that $\|(N-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le 1/|\lambda|$ which would imply that $\lambda(N-\lambda I)^{-1}$ would have a removable singularity at $\lambda=0$, which it most certainly does not. The series for the resolvent of $N$ is easy to compute if $N^{2}=0$ and $N\ne 0$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : The resolvent of an $N\times N$ complex matrix $A$ has first order poles iff the minimal polynomial has no repeated roots, which is equivalent to the diagonalizability of $A$. Poles of higher order are precisely due to nilpotent components in the Jordan normal form. The order of a pole at $\lambda$ is the same as the size of the largest Jordan block with diagonal $\lambda$.

Comment: Isee your point and I certainly agree about poles of nilpotent matrices. So there must be somewhere a flaw!

Comment: @Freeze_S : I think I pointed this out to you once before, but it seemed not to be noticed. This time I wanted to make sure you correct the false impression because the existence of such an estimate would force every matrix to be diagonalizable. A version is satisfied by generators of bdd $C^{0}$ semigroups, too, which is important as well because higher order poles may prevent taking logs of a matrix to get a generator (the nilpotent case is an example of what goes wrong because, for example, an $N\times N$ nilpotent matrix $A$ of order $N$ has no square root (why?).)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the study of spectra by divergence behavior yet but it seems fine what you say: Nilpotents have higher order poles and as such precisely cover the nondiaginalizble part. Now my inequality accidentally had the wrong direction: $\|R(\lambda)\|\geq\frac{1}{d(\lambda,\sigma)}$ That fits nicely with what you pointed out: The resolvent diverges at least as fast as a pole of first order!

Comment: Besides, now your answer fits nicely as answer as it says that nilpotents necessarily give strict inequality. Would you mind adapting it? (Or me?)

Comment: @Freeze_S : I suggest that you adapt it, and I'd be glad to look it over.

Comment: Ok cool thanks! :) *(But please cross-check as I might still make some mistakes.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : I modified only the last sentence concerning diagonalizability of a matrix.

Comment: Alright. Thanks again! ;)